# Implementing Knockout components dependency injection using Typescript

Tags: knockout.js, dependency-injection, typescript1.8

Is there a way to implement dependency injection using Knockout Components.I would like to be able to swap different implementations of a service in a component.For example I would like to use different implementation of a service that implements a Store .One service can use ajax while another service can use HTML storage.The reason I need this is to be able to quickly mock up my app on the client side without worrying about the server side using the HTML storage and then when everything is fine I can hook up the ajax service to test the integration.

Comment: First: Use interfaces. Then you can make your own implementation of amd, to store modules and dependencies. Or use the full amd.js, but that might be overkill, since you just need a store of components matching interfaces.

Comment: I am using webpack so it is more tricky as to how to setup the dependency configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can use agnostic component like bottle.js (https://github.com/young-steveo/bottlejs) or simpleDijs (https://github.com/avighier/simple-dijs), the last one is the more easy to use I have found

Comment: It's always a good practice to provide a simple example in your answer. If the mentioned sites are down or whatever your answer becomes useless.